# Mount cifs with files owned by user

Tags: linux, mount

I want to be able to mount a SMB share from my nas to my home folder and the files be owned by my account rather than root.  For example currently I have:

```
ben@TP:~$ ls -la ~/nas_home/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 ben users 4096 May 29 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 ben users 4096 May 29 12:06 ..
```

If i then run the mount and list the files however, they are owned by root.

```
ben@TP:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=ben //192.168.1.20/home ~/nas_home/
[sudo] password for root: 
Password for ben@//192.168.1.20/home:  **********              
ben@TP:~$ ls -la ~/nas_home/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 29 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 ben  users 4096 May 29 12:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 29 12:09 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 27 12:24 Mail Archive
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 27 09:53 @Recycle
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 27 13:24 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     0 May 27 11:03 Techdocs
```

If i try to run the mount as a user, I get this message:

```
This program is not installed setuid root -  "user" CIFS mounts not supported.
```

Whilst I believe i can address the rights to mount with setuid, I'm concerned this may present a security risk.

Whats the best way to address this please - ideally at the point of mounting?  I am aware I could just run a chown after mounting.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to mount CIFS, you need to specify the credentials for the login.
You did it thru

```
-o username=
```

If you want to bind the mountpoint to a specific user, you need to specify the GID/UID thru the options

```
-o uid=$(id -u ben),gid=$(id -g ben)
```

The whole command then becames:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=ben,uid=$(id -u ben),gid=$(id -g ben) //192.168.1.20/home ~/nas_home/
```

Comment: BTW : this is a duplicate of [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown)

Comment: Thats great - thank you.